# Do shells have a command equivalent of the "|" pipe symbol? I need something like that in Emacs org-mode tables

Tags: pipe, emacs, character-encoding, table, org-mode

I like to construct commands which use the `|` pipe symbol in org tables and  `|` symbol messes them up. Do bash et al have a text command that is the equivalent of the symbol?

Are there alternative ways of constructing the commands without using the pipe symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of. Fix your data handing pipeline if it relies on a standard character being unused - it should at the very least allow for quoted fields or offer escaped delimiter support.

Comment: Can an alternate character for the be used for pipe operator in a shell session?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Fix your data handling, not your shell usage.